# using julia dash with websockets

Tags: websocket, push-notification, julia, real-time, plotly-dash

I like to use dash-extensions for python for websocket interaction.
I use it for:

- Updating client content without server interaction
- Pushing updates from the server to the client(s)
- Running long processes asynchronously

Is there a similar thing for julia?
PS: I know about DCC_interval to make plots reactive. But I am looking for a real push notification, and also the ability to change the dashboard externally without user interaction, where the timing comes from a different process and is not given by DCC_interval.

Dash extensions for python using webs sockets allows exactly that. I am looking for a Julia way to do the same thing.